# How to disable TextBox MenuFlyout when it is in edit mode

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am working on an app on windows phone.

I have a MenuFlyout for a TextBox. How can I disable the MenuFlyout when TextBox is in editing mode?
(i.e when user has tapped on it and the keyboard has launched)?
And re-enable it when user has done editing (when keyboard is closed).

This is my xaml code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="ListItem" Holding="OnHolding">   
                            <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                <MenuFlyout>
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Uid="DeleteListItemMenuItem"
                                                Command="{Binding MenuCommand}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                </MenuFlyout>
                            </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                        </TextBox>
```

And this is my code behind:

```
 private void OnListItemHolding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
            if (textBox == null) return;

            // this event is fired multiple times. We do not want to show the menu twice
            if (args.HoldingState != HoldingState.Started) {
                return;
            }


            // If the menu was attached properly, we just need to call this handy method
            FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(textBox );
        }
```

Comment: Show some code please.  Interested on how you were able to manage this.  The way I did with `FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout` doesn't have any of your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is to checked the focus state before launching the FlyOut like so

```C#
private void TextBox_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{           
    if (e.HoldingState == Windows.UI.Input.HoldingState.Completed)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        if (tb.FocusState == Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Unfocused)
        {
            FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout((FrameworkElement)sender);
        }
    }         
}
```

---

If the TextBox is in editing mode it has a `FocusState` of `Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Pointer`